# To what extent does Node.js replace Apache2?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, apache

I'm in the process of updating an old piece of software (running Apache2, PHP, MariaDB, HTML, CSS) to use a React frontend. I'm completely new to React and I'm between beginner and intermediate with vanilla JavaScript so I've been researching this the last few days.

My confusion is about backend with a React web app. If I want to keep the existing architecture in place aside from frontend, will I be able to painlessly have my apache2/php integrate with my React app? And I'm also confused about the role of Node.js. Some places describe it as just extra libraries, and some places describe it as an Apache2 replacement. I think the source of my confusion is that so far in learning React and Node it always requires me to run npm start. Which feels very much like running a server like apache.

I guess in a nutshell my question is - what will my project structure look like when using a React frontend? Will I have just javascript files and host that on Apache? Or will this need to be run on Node? And where does my PHP fit in, will this need re-written in JS?

EDIT : **For further clarification. I'm asking about the differences between a Node.js server and Apache2 server. That's the focus of my issue. Additional points of discussion to help me understand the problem are how PHP and React fit into all this, and whether my understanding of Node as an Apache-like tool is correct. Hopefully that makes this question less broad**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of building a React app against an existing set of web services: Node.js is used only at build time. It is used to execute the build tools which generate static files which are deployed on your Apache HTTP server.

Node.js is also used to run the development server for the React application that hot reloads it as you save changes to the source code.

---

Node.js **can** be used to run an HTTP server which hosts web services written in JavaScript (which which case it either replaces Apache or sits behind Apache (which is configured to act as a reverse proxy) … but that isn't your use case.